# How to simulate a random variable, knowing its cumulative distribution function is a product of other CDF

Tags: probability, statistics

Let X be a random continuous random variable and $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ other continuous random variable (independent). I know the cumulative distribution functions for $X_i$ and that the CDF of X is the product of the other 3: $F(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{3}F_i(x)$.I want to simulate $10^4$ values for X using R-Studio (I am not very interested in the code itself, I want to understand the math behind it).

**In particular**
$X_i$ ~ $N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$

Intuitively, to create one value which has distribution X, I would have to generate $x_1,x_2,x_3$ with distributions $X_1,X_2,X_3$ respectively, then calculate the product. I have no mathematical proof to back this up though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X_1, X_2,X_3$ are independent

then $F_1(x)\,F_2(x)\,F_3(x)$ is the probability they are all less than or equal to $x$

i.e. the probability $\max(X_1, X_2,X_3)$ is less than or equal to $x$

so you can simulate $X_1, X_2,X_3$ as independent random varaibles with their respective distributions

and then set $X=\max(X_1, X_2,X_3)$.

Comment: "then F1(x)F2(x)F3(x)
 is the probability they are all less than or equal to x" and this is true because $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are independent? (I forgot to mention they are independent)

Comment: @Mejay The probability all the independent events occur is the product of the probabilities that each occurs.